# How do you change starting point on a polyline? (split tool)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, line, splitting

There must be an easy fix for this.  I am using the split tool and I want it to split a polyline into equal parts.  For some reason, it is starting in the middle of my polyline.  How do I force it to start where I want it to? I am using ArcGIS v. 10.1.

Answer (score 4):

Explode the polyline to ensure it is not a multi-geometry. Run Repair features on the polyline features class which may re-order the line segments.  Additionally, if you need to reverse the line orientation, which flips the start and end vertices, you can select the line while editing, click the "Edit Vertices" button, right click on the line and select flip.